# Creating custom properties in spring boot for application.properties returns into NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When i was trying to use custom properties i get stuck on a null pointer. But i can't see what i'm doing wrong. Can you see where the exception come from ?

This is where i create my custom configurations

```
@ConfigurationProperties("custom")
public class CustomProperties {


    private String awsKey ="testvalue";

    private String awsSecret="testvalue";
//getters and setters
}
```

Inside the application.properties i overwrite the values

When i use the `RestController` it works fine and the properties are are overwritten with values from `application.properties`

```
@RestController
@EnableConfigurationProperties(CustomProperties.class)
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomProperties properties;

    private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestController.class);



    @RequestMapping(value = "/createstuf", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public  Map<String,Object> createStuff(@RequestBody Stuff stuff ,@AuthenticationPrincipal Principal principalUser) throws IOException {


        //THIS WORKS and returns the values i want
        System.out.println(this.properties.getAwsKey());
       System.out.println(this.properties.getAwsSecret());


        //BUT WHEN I USE THIS CLASS I GET A NullPointerException
        testClass testClass = new testClass();

        testClass.ShowME();


          return model;

    }
```

This is the class where i get the `NullPointerException`.
What i wrong with this class and why do i get the exception ?

```
@Service
@EnableConfigurationProperties(CustomProperties.class)
public class testClass {


    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClientController.class);


    @Autowired
    private CustomProperties customProperties;



    public void ShowME (){

        LOGGER.info(this.customProperties.getAwsKey());
        LOGGER.info(this.customProperties.getAwsSecret());

    }

}
```

This is my application.properties file

```
custom.aws-key =xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
custom.aws-secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

This is the full error i'm getting

```
2015-12-18 10:51:52.011 ERROR 6620 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
```

Comment: And why should auto wiring happen in a bean instance you are creating yourself...

Comment: Can you perhaps also show the stacktrace? That way, we can see where the NullPointer exactly comes from. My guess would be that both your class name and your instance name are called "testClass" (while class name should start with a capital, i.e. TestClass)

Comment: Sure, add the error output in the console which gives you such information...

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils i update my answer.

Comment: @RJPijpker This is not the problem i renamed the class to be sure but i get the same error

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm still learing about spring. Why is this bad or not done ?

Comment: Spring only injects dependencies in beans it knows and controls. Your bean is outside the control of spring and will never receive any dependencies. (Well actually there are ways but generally not a route you want to take)

Comment: So it would be better to pass the values into a method to the testClass. And remove @Autowired from it.

Comment: What is your `testClass` for thing. Do you really need fresh instances each time or can it be a spring managed bean. It depends on what you want to achieve. But the answer to your question (why the null pointer) is that spring simply doesn't know your bean instance.

Comment: @M.Deinum You where right i never thought of that. When i create an     Autowired testClass inside the restcontroller it works fine. If you want you can create an answer and i gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring will only inject dependencies into bean instances it knows about. However in your code you are doing `new testClass()` which creates a fresh instance of the bean outside the scope and reach of Spring. The result is that no dependencies are injected and hence you get `NullPointerException`.

If you want dependencies inject add a `testClass` field to your controller and put `@Autowired` on it. You will now get the properly configured instance.

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your `CustomProperties.class` with `@Component` and you're able to autowire the bean into your other components.